# only load iframes when called by event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have a webpage with a zipcode finder on it. The page is here http://www.medicalwastedisposaltexas.org/locations.php

The page takes forever to load because; in the background all of these google map iframes are loading.

My question is; Is there a way to only load the iframe when called? So the maps wouldn't load until the zip code is entered and the go button is clicked?

CODE:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var zipCodes = [60538,60504];
      $("#buttontest").click(function(){
      var zipIndex = zipCodes.indexOf(parseInt($("#full_day").val()));
      $("#zipMessage > div").hide("fast");
      var zipId = zipIndex > -1 ? zipCodes[zipIndex] : "Error";
     $("#zip"+zipId).show("fast");
     });

     $("#full_day").keydown(function(e){
     if(e.which === 13){
        $("#buttontest").click();
         }
      });
   });
```

WORKING EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7SPGh/20/

Comment: iframes are loaded because of the `src` attribute. if you don't fill it at first but only when zipcode is entered, that will do the trick.

Comment: You should use only one iframe and set src when needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `src` attribute from your iframe and assign it after search:

```
$('#iframe_id').attr('src', 'http://maps.google.com/?params=');
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7SPGh/28/

Comment: I am not doing something right can you use this example on fiddle and update the code as suggested?? http://jsfiddle.net/7SPGh/20/

Comment: Updated answer, check the example.

Comment: I have another question I posted about this specific topic and code.